# Does subclassing cause a class to stop implementing an interface?

Tags: java, inheritance

Here are relevant classes and methods:

```
public class BoardTile implements BoardCoordinate

public class WordPath extends LinkedList<BoardTile>

public void inputCoordinates(Collection<BoardCoordinate> coords)
```

Basically, what is going on here is this: I'm writing a bot for a flash game, and I have an interface called BoardCoordinate to represent a location on the board. A class representing a tile on the board is called BoardTile, and since it knows its location, it implements the BoardCoordinate interface.

I have a list of tiles which represents a path over the board, which is actually a LinkedList of BoardTiles. Finally, I have a method where I pass a collection of BoardCoordinates to my java.awt.Robot, which inputs the requested path to to the flash game. The Collection is passes for the sake of avoiding potentially ugly coupling between the screen scraper class and my data processing package.

So then, here is the offending code:

```
/* The highest scoring path found. */
Wordpath highest = null;
/* ...
 * ... find the highest scoring path, etc. 
 */
if (longest != null) {
    screen.inputCoordinates(longest);
}
```

The compiler error I get is this: The method inputCoordinates(Collection) in the type Screen is not applicable for the arguments (WordPath).

But WordPath is a LinkedList of BoardCoordinate's! And LinkedList is a Collection! What's going on here?

Of course, I can bite the bullet and accept the coupling, but this is firstly not what I want to do and, secondly, a learning opportunity...

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I'd like to suggest a small change to either design or class naming. A `BoardTile` is something you place (or have) on a game map or game board. But such a tile isn't a coordinate, it **has-a** coordinate. Either the design or the naming of the interface should reflect this "real world" property. A small change now that usually pays off later when you either try to understand your own code (personal experience...) or once you're in the need to communicate your design (another personal experience ;-) ) In your case I'd change the design towards composition. I'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `LinkedList<BoardTile>` isn't a `Collection<BoardCoordinate>` though, due to generic variance. For example, consider:

```
collection.add(new OtherBoardCoordinate());
```

where `OtherBoardCoordinate` is a `BoardCoordinate` but not a `BoardTile`. You wouldn't want one of those in your linked list, would you?

If `inputCoordinates` only needs to *read* from the collection, then modify its signature like this:

```
public void inputCoordinates(Collection<? extends BoardCoordinate> coords)
```

That basically says, "The argument has to be a collection of some type which extends BoardCoordinate, but I don't care exactly what the type is." Within `inputCoordinates` you won't be able to add items to the collection - preventing the sort of problem I mentioned at the start.

See [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more details (look up "wildcards").

An alternative is to make `WordPath` extend `LinkedList<BoardCoordinate>` instead, and just *happen* to add `BoardTile` values to it. (Do you definitely need to *extend* `LinkedList`, by the way? I rarely find myself extending collection classes. Maybe it's appropriate in your case though.)

Comment: But how can OtherBoardTile be a BoardTile without implementing  BoardCoordinate? Does it not inherit its parent's methods, thereby implementing BoardCoordinate?

Comment: @Alex: Sorry, I had it the wrong way round. It should be OtherBoardCoordinate which isn't a BoardTile.

Answer (score 0):

```
class B extends A { ... }

Collection<A> collectionA;
List<A> listA;
List<B> listB;

listA = listB; // error

collectionA = listB; // error
```

**Even though `B extends A`, `List<B>` is *NOT* a subclass of `List<A>`.  Nor is `List<B>` a subclass of `Collection<A>`.**

Its counter-intuitive at first.  The way to think about it is:

```
List<A> listA;
// This declaration means that listA promises to point to a List that
// accepts any instance of 'A' or subclasses of 'A'

List<A> listA = new List<A>();
listA.add(new A()); 
// this is legal because listA promises to put to lists that accept 'A's

List<B> listB = new List<B>();
// new List<B>() creates a list that can hold only instances
// of 'B' or subclasses of 'B'

listA = listB;
// error - broken promise - allowing this assignment would means listA
// will now point to a list that will *NOT* accept an 'A', in direct
// conflict with what is promised by its listA's declaration

listA.add(new A());
// if the above assignment were allowed, then this line would allow
// an `A` to be added to  a list that can only hold `B`s

void myMethod(List<A> listA) { }

myMethod(listB);
// error - broken promise - allowing this parameter would means listA
// (in myMethod) will now point to a list that will *NOT* accept an 'A',
// in direct conflict with what is promised by its listA's declaration
```

The same argument holds if you substitute `Collection<A>` in place of `List<A>` in the above example.

---

***There is a possible solution though.***

If `screen` will only read from the collection `coords`, then using a wildcard should work:

```
public void inputCoordinates(Collection<? extends BoardCoordinate> coords)
```

`inputCoordinate` will now accept a `List<BoardTile>` argument.

However, there is a catch.  `inputCoordinate` will be able to read from `coords`, e.g. you can call `coords.get(i)`, but it won't be able to insert anything into `coords` (e.g. you cannot call `coords.add()`.  More generally, because of the `? extends XXX`, you can call methods that return the type parameter (e.g. `XXX get(...)`), but you won't be able to call any methods that use the type parameter as a method parameter type (e.g. `void add(XXX arg)`).